# How can I change the height of sheet modal in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on a model that I build by adding sheet to the HStack

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showModal, onDismiss: {
                        print(self.showModal)
                    }){
                        ModalView(message: "this is a modal view")
                    }
```

but the modal just fills the whole screen, is there any way that I can change the height of it?
[image]

I want something like this
[image]

Comment: There is not such feature for standard sheet now.

Comment: Ah, that's so sad. So do you know how can I make it with other ways plz?